# get html from external url in GreaseMonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm looking to write some greaseMonkey script that combines html from external url's into the current page. 

 I heard that it might be a problem doing so in JavaScript, because of the Same Origin Policy, but does GreaseMonkey support server side scripting which are requied for that (jQuery), or is the get-method via some external js library/api I can use for that?

[Edit] Is it possible to "get" the html by adding iframe with reference to external url in it?

Comment: jQuery is generally not used for server side scripting... and Greasemonkey scripts generally don't rely on explicit server side scripting.

Answer (score 5):

[GM_xmlhttpRequest](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest) is not affected by Same Origin Policy

Comment: There's a problem with an update : Greasmonkey deprecated all `GM_*`functions in favour of web standards like AJAX. So I can't expect them to continue to work in the future.

Comment: @user2284570, Could you provide a link with details of this?

Answer (score 1):

As Dr.Molle said, Greasemonkey has an API that allows you to bypass the same origin policy: GM_xmlhttpRequest.

Unfortunately the jQuery AJAX methods don't use the Greasemonkey API to issue their requests, so you will need to manually use the Greasemonkey API rather than relying on the jQuery AJAX methods.  If you absolutely must use jQuery, it should be possible to edit the `createStandardXHR()` method; just add `GM_`.

Comment: Which is actually not that bad, as the syntax is very similar to that of `$.ajax` ;)

Comment: Yes, it's not really unfortunate at all, unless you know jQuery already and had planned to use that.

Comment: @MikeEdwards : There's a problem with an update : Greasmonkey deprecated all `GM_*`functions in favour of web standards like AJAX. So I can't expect them to continue to work in the future.